# What negative impacts should I tolerate if I change ALL files in a Next.js project from .js to .jsx?

Tags: next.js

We're using Vite + React for our administratio panel and Qwik + Vite for our landing pages.

These projects use `.jsx` file extensions (we're not using TypeScript).

However, Next.js uses `.js` by default.

We consider changing Next.js `.js` files to `.jsx` so that all of our JavaScript files across of our projects are the same.

However, since the default configuration of Next.js is `.js` we wonder if there is a philosophical reason behind it or not.

If we change the `.js` to `.jsx` in Next.js, what consequences would it have? If nothing, how can we do it?

I can't find any resources on the documentation file.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no problem. finally, adding `x` after `.js` is just to give us a quick confirmation if the file uses a babel template (if it contains a component or not).

just like using `.mjs` for `.js` files with module syntax you can completely use `.js` instead of `.mjs` without any problem